# Measuring Area on Maxscripts

Tags: area, measure, units-of-measurement, 3dsmax, maxscript

So I/m trying to get an Area of Mesh in 3dsMax, But with MaxScripts.

I saw this posts about getting mesh face areas and getting sum of them.

http://www.scriptspot.com/forums/3ds-max/general-scripting/measuring-area

```
(
local obj= selection[1]
local theFaces= getFaceSelection obj
local theArea= meshop.getFaceArea obj theFaces
messageBox("The Area = "+(theArea as string))
)
```

But number I get is not same as What you get from Utilites - Measure. I know I can't access Utilites Panel through Maxscripts, But I want at least same output.

I'm still short at English, So if I have been rude/or Questions not understandable, I sincerely apologize and Feedbacks are welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are differents and all the faces are selected, the most probable reason is that the node is scaled. Meshops work on object level (in this case, we can say baseobject level) so you'd have to multiply that number by the scale of the scene node.

Comment: Multiply it by the scale squared. Surface area increases exponentionally when scaled up.